# jquery : Onclick of a div - get id of following div

Tags: jquery, css, html, onclick

While clicking on a div (any 'resultsMainContainer' div) i should get the div id with class 'result' inside that particular div.

```
<div class="resultsMainContainer">
 <div id="48" class="sbsCard panel  result">
   abcd
 </div>
</div>

<div class="resultsMainContainer">
 <div id="49" class="someCard result">
  aabb
 </div>
</div>

<div class="resultsMainContainer">
 <div id="50" class="sbsCard panel3 result">
   nnaaa
 </div>
</div>

<div class="resultsMainContainer">
 <div id="33" class="sbsCard panel  result">
   abcddd
 </div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.resultsMainContainer', function() {
         alert($(this).next(".result").attr("id"));
});
```

But it's does not seems working.
Is there any other idea/options ?
Or did i made any mistake :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) or [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of `.next()`

```
$('body').on('click', '.resultsMainContainer', function() {
     alert($(this).children(".result").attr("id"));
});
```

and

use .prop() instead of .attr()

```
alert($(this).children(".result").prop("id"));
```

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Great ! That was a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/), change to:

```
alert($(this).find(".result").attr("id"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use find instead of next, as .result is inside "resultsMainContainer" not next to it.

```
$('body').on('click', '.resultsMainContainer', function() {
  alert($(this).find(".result").attr("id"));
});
```